# Stack Frame in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I'm taking an assembly course and I'm having issues with the stack frame. One of the requirements is to pass parameters by using the stack rather than registers. I'm attempting to pass a variable by reference and then change the value of that variable in the procedure. Here's what I have thus far. `WriteString` and `ReadDec` are from a (Irvine) library that came with the book.

```
.data
numVal  DWORD ?
.code
main PROC
    PUSH    OFFSET numVal
    CALL    GetNumber
    exit
main ENDP
GetNumber PROC
    PUSH    edx
    PUSH    ebp
    MOV     ebp, esp

    CALL    ReadDec                ; gets what the user inputs and puts in eax
    MOV     [ebp+12], eax
    ; MOV    numVal, eax           ; this works just fine

    POP     ebp
    POP     edx
    RET     4
GetNumber ENDP
END main
```

However, if I try to print out or use `numVal` at some other point, it comes back as 0, regardless of what is entered by the user. I'm assuming it's sending whatever the user enters to `ebp+12`, which is referring to that address rather than `numVal`. So, if that is correct, is there a way to do this by passing `numVal` by reference or otherwise? Or is my commented out line, `MOV numVal, eax` the only way to do it?

PS. This is homework, I tried to tag it as such but it didn't allow me to.

PPS. This is also my first time posting on overflow, I'd be more than grateful for any constructive criticism to improve posting, etiquette, etc.

Comment: Your posting looks fine.  We no longer tag questions as homework: The nature of the question is usually hint enough if we should answer it or guide you to an answer.

Comment: What is the parameter passing convention of ReadDec?  Another assembly interface?  `C` calling convention for x86?  Pascal convention for protected mode 386?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. It was a library we were told to use from day one and I wasn't able to find what it was doing. When it's called it waits for the user to enter a number, it reads a 32-bin unsigned decimal integer and returns the value to EAX.

Comment: Does ReadDec expect any parameters to be passed to it?  Maybe there is an example in your documentation?

Comment: It doesn't expect any parameters. I've used in two other programs and has worked fine and I've used in the same manner as I have here. The Irvine library also allows me to print out the contents of the registers. I've put this in right after calling ReadDec and EAX contains the value the user put in. After calling GetNumber, I've moved the value of numVal into EAX and then printed the contents of the register and does not show the value the user inputted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "dereference" the parameter passed.

```
GetNumber PROC
    PUSH    edx
    PUSH    ebp
    MOV     ebp, esp

    CALL    ReadDec                ; gets what the user inputs and puts in eax
    MOV     edx, [ebp+12] ; edx now has "offset numVal"
    mov     [edx], eax ; put result of ReadDec there
    ; MOV    numVal, eax           ; this works just fine

    POP     ebp
    POP     edx
    RET     4
GetNumber ENDP
```

I wouldn't have pushed edx - at least not where you did - but it "should" work. Untested!

Comment: Great that worked! I pushed/popped EDX because there was some other code I omitted that used EDX. So, this worked because we placed numVal on EDX and then moved EAX to EDX? Why wasn't this the case when trying to put EAX on [ebp + 12]?

Comment: `[ebp + 12]` holds the address (offset part of the address) of numVal. Replacing it with `eax` (returned by ReadDec) doesn't put the value in your variable. It merely puts the value on the stack, which is not where we want it. Re-read the section on "passing by reference". Surely the book explains this before expecting you to do it(?). (I haven't read Kip Irvine's book, actually...)